# Why df[0] is not returning 0th indexed column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Here I am applying OneHotEncoder to one of my dataframe columns.

```
dfcars= pd.read_excel('cars.xlsx')
ohe=OneHotEncoder()
temp1= pd.DataFrame(ohe.fit_transform(dfcars[['Car Model']]).toarray())
ohe.categories_
dfcars = pd.concat([dfcars,temp1], axis=1)
```

This is my dataset after aplying OHE:
[dfcars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhTDN.png)

`dfcars[0]` doesn't display the the first column.
`dfcars[4]` shows error.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can access any column using the column name `df['column_name']` and the same thing is happening here with `df[0]` as one of the column created after applying `OneHotEncoder` is named as `0`.

To slice the dataframe using index values, one can use `iloc`.

`df.iloc[:,:1]` can be used to access the first column.

Answer (score 0):

This may be happening because dfcars[0] syntax is df[column_name_string] and you have a column of the name "0" but you don't have a column of the name "4".
You can rename the columns before concatenating:

```
temp1= pd.DataFrame(ohe.fit_transform(dfcars[['Car Model']]).toarray(),columns=['Category_0', 'Category_1', 'Category_2'])
dfcars = pd.concat([dfcars,temp1], axis=1)
```

For `categories_` attribute of `OneHotEncoder`, you can visit [sklearn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html).